# Netty4 Unexpected exception in the selector loop

Tags: java, netty

I have implemented a HTTP client using Netty4.0.0.CR3. I am managing a pool of client connection toward server, Based on certain event an event handler thread pick one connection from the pool, send the HTTP request to server, wait for response (`FullHttpResponse`) and then release connection back to pool.

Now problem which I am facing is that under heavy load I am getting these `warnings` in my log, 
`

> 15:56:59.828 nioEventLoopGroup-37-1 WARN  i.n.c.nio.NioEventLoop -
>   Slf4JLogger.warn() : Unexpected exception in the selector loop.
>   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor
>   terminated    at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:711)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.0.CR3.jar:na]     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:306)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.0.CR3.jar:na]     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:696)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.0.CR3.jar:na]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.invokeLater(AbstractChannel.java:968)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.0.CR3.jar:na]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:750)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.0.CR3.jar:na]     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.closeAll(NioEventLoop.java:521)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.0.CR3.jar:na]     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:329)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.0.CR3.jar:na]     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:114)
>   [netty-all-4.0.0.CR3.jar:na]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>   [na:1.6.0_45]

`

Now, what i want to ask is, will these warnings will create any problem, if yes any pointers on how to solve this or I can ignore them.

Regards !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you shutdown EventLoopGroup before all requests are handled. Be sure to use EventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully().

If you shutdown the EventLoopGroup before everything is handled it will produce such an error

Comment: Thanks for the replying. I am not calling EventLoopGroup.shutdown(), instead in my client I am calling `channel.closeFuture();` followed by `bootstrap.shutdown();` for clearing up connection toward server. Is this the correct way ? or should i do it differently

Comment: Call EventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully()

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more query,I am using apache commons pool, creating multiple http connections toward the server and using a common (`NioEventLoopGroup`) for each client. Now if a connection is closed how do I do the cleanup, as I am calling `EventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully()` only at the closure of pool. How do I manage individual connection cleanup.

Comment: What you mean with connection cleanup ?

Comment: Http-server closes connections, or there is no activity idle connections are needed to be released, as per pool configuration. For such connection any specific cleanup is required.

Comment: I don'T think there is anything special required here.